# rspec-puppet with ruby 1.8.7 gives "unexpected ')'" error but all other ruby versions work

Tags: ruby, puppet, ruby-1.8.7

While developing spec tests for a Puppet module, TravisCI tests against various Ruby/Gem/Puppet versions. Often all tests work on all versions except with Ruby 1.8.7.  There the tests don't even start. Instead you get an error that mentions `configuration.rb:1105` and `syntax error, unexpected ')'`.

Here is one [example](https://travis-ci.org/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/jobs/59028991):

```
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load': /home/travis/build/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/spec/classes/haproxy_spec.rb:347: syntax error, unexpected ')' (SyntaxError)
/home/travis/build/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/spec/classes/haproxy_spec.rb:355: syntax error, unexpected kDO_BLOCK, expecting kEND
/home/travis/build/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/spec/classes/haproxy_spec.rb:364: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

I've seen this on multiple projects.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ruby-1.8.7 was less forgiving about extra commas.  If you look at the line following the one with `configuration.rb:1105`, it mentions a file. That is the file that has an extra comma or some other issue.  In the above case, the problem is `haproxy_spec.rb:355`; in older Ruby the last line of a hash must omit the comma.

Here's the diff between the version that triggers the error and the version that fixes it:

```
         it 'should create directory /etc/haproxy' do
           subject.should contain_file('/etc/haproxy').with(
-            'ensure' => 'directory',
+            'ensure' => 'directory'
           )
         end
       end
```

As you'll see in the next [TravisCI build](https://travis-ci.org/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/builds/59030351), this fixed it.